# Why is GCC throwing filesystem_error cannot copy

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17, filesystems, gcc12

I'm working on an app that writes/copies files and thought of updating the code to [C++17's filesystem](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-12.3.0/libstdc++/api/a01575.html).

I'm on Windows 11 using `g++ v12.2` with **MSYS2 MinGW 64-bit**.

Below is a summary of my app's behavior.

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;
 
int main() {
    fs::create_directories("sandbox");
    
    std::ofstream ofs;
    ofs.open ("sandbox/file1.txt", std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app);
        ofs << "hello";
    ofs.close();
    
    std::cout << "test copy file" << std::endl;
    fs::copy("sandbox/file1.txt", "sandbox/file2.txt", fs::copy_options::overwrite_existing); // copy file
    
    static_cast<void>(std::system("tree"));
    
    //sometime later, file is updated
    ofs.open ("sandbox/file1.txt", std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app);
        ofs << "world";
    ofs.close();
    
    //sometime later, need to update file2 via copy
    std::cout << "test copy file again" << std::endl;
    fs::copy("sandbox/file1.txt", "sandbox/file2.txt", fs::copy_options::overwrite_existing); // copy file

    fs::remove_all("sandbox");
}
```

Above code was compiled with:

```sh
g++ -c -std=gnu++17 testcopy.cpp -o testcopy.o
g++ ./testcopy.o  -o testcopy.exe
```

Then, you'll get this:

```sh
./testcopy.exe
test copy file
Folder PATH listing for volume Acer
Volume serial number is 38B3-48F3
C:.
└───sandbox
test copy file again
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::filesystem::__cxx11::filesystem_error'
  what():  filesystem error: cannot copy: File exists [sandbox/file1.txt] [sandbox/file2.txt]
```

I wonder if I have to `release`, `free`, or `close` file2.txt after first copy but I don't know how.

Or, possibly, **copy_options** is not supported by GCC on Windows, to which I'm okay defer porting my code to C++17.

I was expecting `copy_options::overwrite_existing` will handle the `File exists` problem.  I've also used `copy_options::update_existing` to no avail.

Comment: Just for completeness, there's no difference when using [`copy_file`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/copy_file) instead of [`copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/copy)?

Comment: Are you running this exact program when you get the exception? It works fine for me on Windows 11.

Comment: File cannot be overwritten , maybe? Permissions do noy allow itor there is a folder with same name (kryptonite of many programs and even of some viruses)

Comment: @TedLyngmo, I'm running exact code on Win11 (build 22621.1848). may I know your GCC version?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I updated to `copy_file` and still got the same error.

Comment: Looks like it slipped through the net: https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/bugs/852/

Comment: What does `fs::equivalent("sandbox/file1.txt", "sandbox/file2.txt")` just before attempting the failing copy say? Also `std::filesystem::is_regular_file` for both is true?

Comment: You should open an issue on GitHub msys2 is maintained there instead of sourceforge.

Comment: ***may I know your GCC version?*** `gcc --version` is the command  regardless of the OS. My gcc in msys2 returns this on the first line: ***gcc.exe (Rev6, Built by MSYS2 project) 13.1.0*** and a RockyLinux in a guest lxc container on a linux host returns this: ***gcc (GCC) 11.3.1 20221121 (Red Hat 11.3.1-4)***